# Changing an element value in the XML file

Tags: xml, powershell

Need help with changing an element value in below XML using PowerShell:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<Root>
<Package>
<ID>001</ID>
<Quantity1>65465</Quantity1>
<Quantity2>CALC</Quantity2>
</Package>
<Package>
<ID>002</ID>
<Quantity1></Quantity1>
<Quantity2>1547625</Quantity2>
</Package>
</Root>
```

I need to loop through the XML file and

- cut value from `<Quantity1>` and paste it to `<Quantity2>` in the first case (ID:001).
- cut value from `<Quantity2>`, paste it to `<Quantity1>` and make `<Quantity2>` equals to 'CALC' in the second case (ID:002).

I've tried this code:

```bsh
[XML]$XMLcontents = [XML](Get-Content $PathToTheFile)
foreach ($i in $XMLcontents.SelectNodes('/Root/Package')) {
   $_.Quantity2 = $_.Quantity1
}
```

but I'm getting the following error:

> The property 'Quantity2' cannot be found on this object.

How to properly reference elements within a node `<Package>`?

Answer (score 1):

First to answer why that fails is becuase you are using **$_** when you should be using **$i** in the foreach.

OK first lets make the object into XML in by declaring it

```
[xml]$XML = @"
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<Root>
<Package>
<ID>001</ID>
<Quantity1>65465</Quantity1>
<Quantity2>CALC</Quantity2>
</Package>
<Package>
<ID>002</ID>
<Quantity1></Quantity1>
<Quantity2>1547625</Quantity2>
</Package>
</Root>
"@
```

Then we will search the root for each package

```
foreach($package in $XML.Root.Package){
}
```

Gather the values and switch them

```
$Q1 = $package.Quantity1
$package.Quantity1 = $package.Quantity2
$package.Quantity2 = $Q1
```

Full script

```
[xml]$XML = @"
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<Root>
<Package>
<ID>001</ID>
<Quantity1>65465</Quantity1>
<Quantity2>CALC</Quantity2>
</Package>
<Package>
<ID>002</ID>
<Quantity1></Quantity1>
<Quantity2>1547625</Quantity2>
</Package>
</Root>
"@

foreach($package in $XML.Root.Package){
    $Q1 = $package.Quantity1
    $package.Quantity1 = $package.Quantity2
    $package.Quantity2 = $Q1
}

$XML.Root.Package
```

If you want to use SelectNodes then you can also do

```
foreach ($i in $XML.SelectNodes('/Root/Package')) {
    $Q1 = $i.Quantity1
    $i.Quantity1 = $i.Quantity2
    $i.Quantity2 = $Q1
}

$XML.SelectNodes('/Root/Package')
```

Answer (score 0):

XML in Powershell can be tricky. I'd do something like this...

```
[xml]$xmlDoc = @"
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<Root>
<Package>
<ID>001</ID>
<Quantity1>65465</Quantity1>
<Quantity2>CALC</Quantity2>
</Package>
<Package>
<ID>002</ID>
<Quantity1></Quantity1>
<Quantity2>1547625</Quantity2>
</Package>
</Root>
"@

$xmlDoc.Root.Package

foreach ( $package in $xmlDoc.Root.Package ) {
    if ( $package.ID.Equals('001') ) {
        $package.Quantity2 = $package.Quantity1
    }

    if ( $package.ID.Equals('002') ) {
        $package.Quantity1 = $package.Quantity2
        $package.Quantity2 = 'CALC'
    }
}

$xmlDoc.Root.Package
```

That first part `[xml]$xmlDoc = @"..."@` I'm creating your XML document. I've stuffed it in a big'ol here-string.

The `$xmlDoc.Root.Package` is there just to show you the original state of your data. You don't need this in your final product.

The foreach loop is where I make the changes. I loop through all the `Package` elements in the `Root` element. For each one, I check the `ID` element's value. If it's "001", I copy that package's `Quantity2` element value to `Quantity1`. If it's "002", I copy `Quantity2` to `Quantity1` then add "CALC" to `Quantity2`. You can see how I'm assigning the values.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

```
# requires -version 6
(Select-Xml -Path C:\path\input.xml -XPath //Package).Node.ForEach{
   $node = $_
   switch ([Int32]$_.ID) {
      1 { $node.Quantity2 = $node.Quantity1 }
      2 {
         $node.Quantity1 = $node.Quantity2
         $node.Quantity2 = 'CALC'
      }
   }
   $node.OwnerDocument.Save('C:\path\input.xml')
}
```